# Could Premium Hats Be Added To Winter Bash

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2012, hat-request

I know the Winter Bash is temporary but for next year, could premium hats be added to the mix. Ones that you can use your reputation to buy? Just thinking of ways reputation could be used for more fun hats or variations of the same hat.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, this is already in the [Winter Bash FAQ](http://winterba.sh/faq):

> ##Can I buy hats from you guys?
> I...we...You know what, [make us an offer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other) and we'll talk. We only accept [unicorn dollars](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/12-million-unicorn-bucks.jpg), though.

All joking aside: we don't like using reputation for anything besides "Look at my awesome" measurements. You can't buy swag or flair with rep -- hats are no different. Remember: hats are *badges you can wear!*

Finally: we have seekrit hats. They're basically the "premium" hats you describe. :)

Comment: o cool, sorry missed it =)

Comment: @Aarthi You said that I got unicorn dollars as my reward. Can I cash those in now?

Comment: @AustinHenley No no no, I said a unicorn would be by with unicorn dollars for you. When/if that unicorn arrives, *then* you can cash out.

Comment: @AustinHenley Also, you must be worthy of the unicorn. Traditional limitations apply.