# Is There A Frosty Hat

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2012, hat-request

I have seen the Santa hat, the reindeer antlers but is there a Frosty hat, complete with a corncob pipe and a button nose? If not, may I suggest one =)

Comment: Looks like people have bad mood today :)

Comment: I wish them a Merry Christmas either way.

Comment: @animuson, please stop with the tag wars

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is **no**, the hats that are displayed on the [Winter Bash site](http://winterba.sh/) are the only hats available.

However, [there *are* Easter Egg hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159695/140951) (odd for Christmas, but, whatever), but it's not been verified what exactly they are (even to mods) or how to get them at the time of this post.

It's a possibility for *next* year, I assume, but the assumption is that the hats that you see are pretty much locked into place for this year.

Comment: [The hats on the Winterbash site aren't the only hats available.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/what-are-the-secret-hats-for-2012)

Comment: @Ullallulloo "However, there *are* Easter Egg hats..."

Comment: took me a minute to get the Easter/Christmas joke you made. Well-played, sir.

Answer (score 2):

## No.

There are, however, secret hats (as casperOne mentioned in his answer) which are awarded by surprise. Have fun finding them! Otherwise: we have no plans to add more hats to the base set at this time -- and I'll put this hat on the list for next year. :)